# Scrolling a panel programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

I've got a PictureBox inside a Panel. 
The SizeMode of the PictureBox has been set in this way:

```
 pcbImage.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
```

The PictureBox Image property has a Bitmap loaded inside it which, initially, has the same width/height of the Panel.
The PictureBox location is (0, 0).

When I press the ZoomIn button I double the size of the image and - correctly - the Panel allows to vertically and horizontally scroll it.

What I'm trying to do is to programmatically position the vertical and horizontal scrollbars so that the center of the image is always displayed after zooming in.

I saw here in SO that I could play with the AutoScrollPosition property of the Panel.
The point is that if I do something like this, for instance:

```
pnlImage.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(pcbImage.Image.Width / 2, pcbImage.Image.Height / 2);
```

...the DisplayRectangle property of the Panel changes to negative values. The result is that when I scroll back to the initial position (left for the H scroll and top for the V scroll) an area with no image appears.

Comment: The **`DisplayRectangle.Location`** shows negative values (corresponding to the negative offset given by the ScrollBars .`Value` property, equal to `AutoScrollPosition` you just set). The `.Size` value reflects the Vertical/Horizontal ScrollBars' new `.Maximum` value. *The result is that when I scroll back to the initial position*: how do you scroll back (other than setting `pnlImage.AutoScrollPosition = Point.Empty`)? Dragging the ScrollBars (it doesn't happen)? Are you also repositioning the PictureBox maybe?

Comment: Btw, this: `pnlImage.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(...)` doesn't seem correct (given the description). You should also check whether the `Image.Size` is larger, in one or both dimensions, than the `Panel.ClientSize`. This also moves the scroll position to the center of the Image (eventually), but it doesn't center the Image in the Panel's ClientRectangle.

Comment: When loading the form the PictureBox (i.e. my image) size is equal to the Panel size. Pressing the ZoomIn button the image doubles the size (and consequently the PictureBox). Horizontal and vertical scroll bars appears in the Panel as shown here: https://i.postimg.cc/zvspX31Q/Fit-Preview1.jpg . What I'm trying to do is to move programmatically to the right (the HScrollBar) and to the bottom (the VScrollBar) so that the center of the image was shown. I tried the solution I mentioned above bu the problem is that this happens: https://i.postimg.cc/FH3FK60C/Fit-Preview2.jpg

Comment: I'm moving the ScroolBars using the mouse, not programmatically. It seems that AutoScrollPosition increases the Panel size, becoming so bigger than the PictureBox

Comment: It doens't.  The panel adapts itself to the size of the controls it's hosting. If that PictureBox is the only child control, what you're showing cannot happen just setting the AutoScrollPosition. Check whether you're re-setting the `PictureBox.Location` somewhere. Maybe when you *double the size* of its Image (you should show that code, too). Or setting the `ScrollBars.Value`. Or there's something in the Resize or Scroll events.

Comment: Just try to clarify better: 1. Loading the image in the PictureBox.Image property, with size equals to the Panel size. 2. Doubling the image size. 3. loading the image again in the PictureBox.Image property. 4. pnlImage.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(_myimage.Width / 2, _myimage.Height / 2). The image is scrolled to the its center but it seems that Panel area became bigger, as you can see in my screenshot

Comment: True, I was relocating it in the function that I call for resizing inside the ZoomIn click event. I wrote the resizing part few months ago and I didn't check it anymore. Thanks for the help